# Can someone help me find dead links in my posts?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, data-explorer

I suspect that there is a data query that will find this for me, but it's been a while since I last ventured onto the data site and I'm hoping that someone will be able to answer this quickly for me.

Due to shifting websites a few years back, many of my posts here contain dead links.  I get the odd notification when someone notices it, but I don't always have the time to deal with it there and then and so when I do have time (such as now), I don't always remember where they are - and I have rather a lot of posts so going through one by one is prohibitive.

So, is anyone able to quickly put together a search on the data query site (and remind me where that site is!) for me to find them?  The key criteria are:

- user: 86
- post contains: ntnu

Then I can figure out which documents I need to upload to my new website (or github) and stop getting notifications about dead links.

Comment: To get the ones with the link as clear text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22www.math.ntnu.no%2F%7Estacey%22

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. That'll get me started, but I suspect that there are many others where there's a link text which is why I want to search the original text rather than the rendered text.

Comment: Can you try this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/877843/find-links#resultSets ?

Comment: @samcarter That looks brilliant ... care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Done :) ________

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query could be a starting point:

https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/877843/find-links#resultSets

Please note that it returns a few "false positives", i.e. answers by other users, but maybe it is good to leave them in so that these posts can be fixed as well.

---

I just learned that there is a `url` key for the search

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Awww.math.ntnu.no%2F%7Estacey

Comment: Looks brilliant.  I'll edit slowly so that I don't spam the front page.